# How to split the I18n keys over multiple lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to do something like this

```
errors.add(:model, I18n.t("group1\
                         .group2\
                         .bla_bla_bla_bla"))
```

The reason I want to do this is rubocop is giving me line length is too long, So I would like to split it over multiple lines

Comment: What seems to be the problem? This should work.

Comment: Could not parse that string properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for a simple:

```
errors.add(:model, I18n.t("group1" \
                         ".group2" \
                         ".bla_bla_bla_bla"))
```

But then you could also go the `join` way:

```
errors.add(:model, I18n.t(["group1",
                           "group2",
                           "bla_bla_bla_bla"].join(".")))
```

It really depends on the specific error rubocop gives you.

Answer (score 2):

Try use heredoc

```
t_key = <<-KEY
  group1\
  .group2\
  .bla_bla_bla_bla
KEY
errors.add(:model, I18n.t(t_key))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative you can use new syntax of `scope` for I18n

`I18n.t(:blah_blah_blash, scope: [:group1, :group2])`